# Error installing Apache (libaprutil)

Tags: apache, installation

While installing apache, I got this error message:

libtool: install: error: cannot install `libaprutil-1.la' to a directory not ending /some_directory

What's wrong?

---

NOTE: I already figured out the issue, but since searching Google was not very helpful, I wrote up this question in the hope of helping others, and possibly myself, with this error in the future.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

apparently `./config --prefix=/mydir` didn't get set correctly the first time. Rerunning a failed apache `make` can be troublesome.
You need to first do a `make clean`, and then retry with the correct --prefix